# Setting ItemController affects nested resource's index model

Tags: ember.js

Say I have a route setup like so:

```
this.resource('projects', function(){
  this.resource('project', { path: "project/:project_id" }, function(){
  ...
```

Currently, I use the ProjectIndexController to display information for the project but if I set ProjectController as an ItemController in the ProjectsController, the model for ProjectIndexController is no longer set.

I can reference the data from a computed property but it won't take as the model/content for the ProjectIndexController even if I set it in the ProjectIndex route.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Likely, it works for me: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nobima/7/edit You'll need to provide more code in order to say what

Comment: Your right, it does work, I even extended your example to the exact scenario I have: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/liduleciza/4/edit

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with a stray 'needs' property set in the project index controller back to the project controller.